# grep text between two tags using perl/sed/awk

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, grep

Could you please tell me how to get the text between two tags in a file. In my file there are so many tags. Below line is extracted in a file. i need to get ACTIONSUM as output. a text between `<TableName modified='1' type='string'> and </TableName> tags`.

Input:

`</WriteMode><TableName modified='1' type='string'><![CDATA[ACTIONSUM]]></TableName><EnableCaseSensitiveIDs type='bol'>`

Ouput:

`ACTIONSUM`

Please suggest the command or script to grep it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can be done with regex-based tools, but it might be better to parse it as XML and extract information that way

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper XML-parsing tool like `xmlstarlet` for this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//TableName[@modified="1" and @type="string"]' -v . filename.xml
```

Or `xmllint`:

```
xmllint --nocdata --xpath '//TableName[@modified="1" and @type="string"]/node()' filename.xml
```

Using a line-based tool like sed for this would result in something that would break when the format of the XML changes in benign ways (such as inserting newlines or shuffling/adding new attributes), which nobody expects.

Comment: Hi Wintermute, i tried xmlstarlet and xmllint...its not working. It is saying failed to load external entity

Comment: Worked for me. Is your XML valid?